# Count number of agents at a node

Tags: java, anylogic

I have set up a polygonal node (called area_wait) that a single type of agent remain at whilst in a queue. I'm trying to find the number of agents at a node using a function. I don't want to count the agents in the queue as I have set up one queue for all waiting agents which might be at different nodes.

I'm using the following code which always returns zero.

```
int count_X = area_wait.agents().size();
```

In fact the list is empty when I check with:

```
List list_X = area_wait.agents();
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the same answer I gave in the anylogic users group which can be found here: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6721800348408791040

so this function you are trying to use doesn't work... unless the thing that is inside the node is a transporter and only if the node has a speed or access restriction... this might either be a bug or something explained poorly on the documentation, but it sounds like a bug to me

If you want to know the number of agents in a node you can use the alternative method count(myAgents,a->a.getNetworkNode()!=null && a.getNetworkNode().equals(yourNode)) but this fails if you change the node position without a moveTo block or some other natural movement (such as defining your node in the agent location parameter of a block)... so.. that's another bug, but maybe it won't apply to you

So summary... no easy and safe solution as far as I know

Comment: Thanks Felipe. Its good to know that it isn't just me making a silly error. Unfortunately defining my node in the agent location is exactly what I'm doing. I'll try and figure out another method.